# Django - model with several tag fields

Tags: python, django, tags

I need a model with several "tag" fields. For example:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    type = SomeTagField()
    manufacturer = SomeTagField()
```

It could be done using many-to-many relationships, but I'm not sure if this is a correct approach. It looks a little bit overcomplicated.

I've tried django-tagit and its `TaggableManager` but without luck:

`ValueError: You can't have two TaggableManagers with the same through model.`

What would be a correct way to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Over-complicated" is subjective, but I would use `ManyToManyField`

```py
class FoodType(models.Model):
    country = SomeField()
    nutrients = SomeField()
    ...


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = SomeField()
    cost = SomeField()
    ...


class Food(models.Model):
    type = models.ManyToManyField(FoodType, ...)
    manufacturer = models.ManyToManyField(Manufacturer, ...)
```